# How to select multiple row in Table row ?Using(ctrl+click) and (Shift+click) in react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Please help me, I have no idea how to solve that problem when user press ctrl +Left click  table row should highlight the row, and in shift + left click It should highlight all the row data where the user clicks from 1 row to 2 last row (example like react-Table multiple row selection).
Not using any 3 party library.

Code:-

```
  const ClickHighlight = (event, ID, ChannelName) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey) {

        }

      if(event.shiftKey) {
           console.log("helloShift");
        }



    }




    return (
        <div className="mainContent">
            <div className="tableHeaderBody">
                <div className="TableText">PlayList</div>  <div className="ClossIcon"><FaCircle style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "10px", height: "10px", alignItems: "right" }} /></div>
            </div>
            <div className="tableBody" >
                <table className="table" id="tableStudent" data-multiple-select-row="true"
                    data-click-to-select="true">
                    <Header
                        headers={headers}
                    />
                    <tbody>
                        {comments.map((comment) => {
                           
                            return (
                                <tr key={comment.idx} tabIndex={comment.idx} className="border_bottom"  onMouseDown={(e) => ClickHighlight(e, comment.ClipName, comment.ChannelName)}>
                                    <td style={{ color: "white", width: "200px" }}>
                                        <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`} alt="Clip Thumbnail" width="50%" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style={{ color: "white", width: "440px" }}>{comment.ClipName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.SlugName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.ChannelName}</td>
```

Please help.

Comment: have you tried holding the highlighted rows (or their ids) in state? That way you can add and remove them in your clickhandler

Comment: No can You give me an example of how can I do that? please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've assumed your component is a functional one, but hopefully this gives you the idea on how to do it anyway. I've also assumed `comments` is a prop of your component:

```
const [highlightedRows, setHighlightedRows] = useState([]);

const ClickHighlight = (event, id, ChannelName) => {
  if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
    // add to highlighted
    setHighlightedRows((current) => {
      if (current.includes(id)) {
        // row is already highlighted. Unhighlight but keep the others
        return current.filter((entry) => entry !== id);
      } else {
        // add row to the current list of highlighted ones
        return [...current, id];
      }
    });
  } else {
    // highlight clicked row and de-highlight others
    setHighLightedRows([id]);
  }
}
```

Now in your return statement you can use the state to either render the row as highlighted or not by matching to the comment's `idx`. Here i've just given each highlighted item a yellow background, but you can style this any way you want.

```
<tbody>
  {comments.map((comment) => {
    const isHighlighted = highlightedRows.includes(comment.idx);
    // we can now conditionally render based on if this flag is true or not           
    return (
      <tr
        key={comment.idx}
        tabIndex={comment.idx}
        className="border_bottom"
        onMouseDown={(e) => ClickHighlight(e, comment.idx, comment.ChannelName)}
        style={ isHighlighted ? { backgroundColor: 'yellow' } : {}}
        >
         <td style={{ color: "white", width: "200px" }}>
           <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64}`} alt="Clip Thumbnail" width="50%" />
         </td>
         <td style={{ color: "white", width: "440px" }}>{comment.ClipName}</td>
         <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.SlugName}</td>
         <td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>{comment.ChannelName}</td>
         ...
```

Comment: thanks,works for ctrl can you tell me,is this ok for shiftkey to highlight all the row start to end  else if (event.shiftKey) {
            setHighlightedRows((current) => {
                if (current.includes(id)) {                                                           
                    return current.filter((previousRow) => previousRow !== id);
                } else {
                    previousRow.push(id);
                    console.log(previousRow);                                  
                    return [...current,previousRow];
});

Comment: That is more complicated functionality, as each row needs to know where it is in the order so that it can update the state correctly.
Your filter won't work because previousRow will only match with id once